# only one parameter getting binded with bindparam in php pdo

Tags: php, pdo

I tried inserting the values to the database by taking them into an array by using php pdo I wrote the fallowing code for the operation

```
$insert = $this->var1->prepare('INSERT INTO person (username,password,email) VALUES (:username,:password,:email)');
        foreach($this->user as $key=>$value)
        {
            $key = ":" . $key;
            $insert->bindParam($key,$value);
        }
        $insert->execute();

        if($insert->rowCount()>0)
        {
            echo "database has sucessfully updated";
            $this->response["status"] = 1;
        }
```

when my array has the input

```
Array
(
[username] => example
[password] => example@password
[email] => example@email
)
```

I get the output as database sucessfully updated according to the code but my database updates in fallowing way

```
username          password         email
example@email     example@email    example@email
```

instead of getting

```
username          password           email
example           example@password   example@email
```

I could not understand mistake in above loop , I tried printing the values of the loop by echo and each time it suceesfully prints the values as required but in database they are stored in above format thankyou

Comment: You could just do `VALUES (?,?,?)` and then pass an array of values in the proper order to `execute()`. `$stmt = $con->prepare($query);`, `$stmt->execute($array);`

Answer (score 0):

`bindParam` takes its input *by reference*, which has this effect when reusing the same variable… use [`bindValue`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindvalue.php) instead.

Answer (score -1):

Use this code, $value by reference, because bindParam needs &$variable

```
foreach($this->user as $key=>&$value)
        {
            $key = ":" . $key;
            $insert->bindParam($key,$value);
        }
```